# Group values of two common rows into one in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has values something like this

```
ID Name Age Value1 Value2
1  Arya      10     
1  Arya              20
2  Sansa     67      
2  Sansa             56
```

I want an output something like this

```
 ID Name Age Value1 Value2
 1  Arya      10     20
 2  Sansa     67     56
```

I know we can use groupby to group them but the Age column is blank because of which I am not able to get the desired result.
Please suggest

Comment: Is possible there is multiple values per groups like `2  Sansa     67` is changed to `1  Arya 67` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with replace empty values to `NaN`s if there is only one value per group and per column:

```
cols = ['Value1','Value2']

df[cols] = df[cols].replace('', np.nan)
df = df.groupby(['ID','Name','Age'])[cols].first()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your df has always 2 values for each `ID`, you could first order the rows, then fill `Value1` and `Value2` and then remove the duplicates:

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Value1'], ascending=[True, False])
df[['Value1', 'Value2']] = df[['Value1', 'Value2']].replace('', np.NaN)
df['Value1'] = df['Value1'].ffill()
df['Value2'] = df['Value2'].bfill()
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
```

Output:

```
   ID   Name Age Value1 Value2
1   1   Arya         10     20
3   2  Sansa         67     56
```

Comment: Be carefull, here is possible some values betwen groups are incorrectly replaced by ffill

Comment: True, but if there are always 2 values for each ID, ordering should work

Comment: Yes, it working if exactly same pattern of data like in samples.

Comment: @jezrael yeah u are right...pattern change can create probelm in the data.

Comment: @jezrael but your solution is not considering the empty column that is creating the issue.

Comment: @SaumyaPandey - If column is empty, `df = df.groupby(['ID','Name','Age'])[cols].first()` should working.